# Ceph octopus, setting autoscale mode from ceph.conf file

Tags: ceph

Since octopus, ceph clusters have the `osd_pool_default_pg_autoscale_mode` flag set to `on` as default.

So far I was able to turn it off from the cli using `ceph config set global osd_pool_default_pg_autoscale_mode off` as described [here](https://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/rados/operations/placement-groups/).

I would like to set it from the ceph.conf file:

```
[global]
...
osd pool default pg autoscale mode = off
pg autoscale mode = off
```

However `ceph osd pool autoscale-status` still shows newly created pools with autoscale turned on, even with pools created after restarting the osd's and mgr's daemons.

Any help would be welcome

Answer (score 0):

```
[global]
# disable pg_autoscaler by default for new pools
osd_pool_default_pg_autoscale_mode = off
```

Putting this in both Monitor and OSDs `ceph.conf` should be works.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. Underscores doesn't seems to matter. Ceph.conf is set on both the manager node and the servers. I have also restarted the OSD's and MGR daemons and tried with a fresh cluster. I have seen this line from the source code also. But it doesn't seem to help.